# What is Wrong with this code it is unable to take command as speech in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```python
import speech_recognition as sr
import win32com.client
import pyttsx3

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")


def say(text):
    print("Speaking......")
    speaker.Speak(text)


def take_command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
            print(f"User said: {query}")
            return query
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return "Sorry from Jarvis"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    say("Hello, I am Jarvis A.I.")
    while True:
        print("Listening....")
        text = take_command()
        say(text)
```

The above Python program is throwing an error message while executing the `take_command()` function. The program is built to run speech recognition on commands, and execute the voice command on the computer. Can anyone help me understand what is causing this error and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Singh\PycharmProjects\AIJarvis\main.py", line 18, in take_command
    audio = r.listen(source)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Singh\PycharmProjects\AIJarvis\venv\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 465, in listen
    assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Singh\PycharmProjects\AIJarvis\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    text = take_command()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Singh\PycharmProjects\AIJarvis\main.py", line 15, in take_command
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\Arpit Singh\PycharmProjects\AIJarvis\venv\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: Check the output of `sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()`, find which device is your microphone, and use `sr.Microphone(device_index=n)` with `n` as the desired device.

Comment: tried it but didn't worked....thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using google's speech to text, adding the following line resolved it. If you haven't tried it,

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:    
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
```